Byobu: Kill foreground process in current window
I use Byobu to run different long-running processes. Sometimes I want to stop these processes. They don't always respond to Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z. Is it possible to make a Byobu hotkey that just finds the foreground process running in the currently-active Byobu window and kill -9 it?

Notes (assuming Linux): (1) It's the terminal driver that intercepts ^C or ^Z character and sends SIGINT or SIGTSTP. The terminal may be configured not to do this, so it's not necessarily that the process ignores anything, respective signal sent with kill may still work. (2) The signal (from keyboard or from kill) may work but if the parent does not properly react to SIGCHLD then you may think the child is still there silently doing something. (3) You wrote "the foreground process" (singular). SIGINT or SIGTSTP from keyboard goes to the foreground process group.

~/bin/_byobu_kill_process.sh:
#!/bin/bash

window_id=$(tmux display-message -p '#I')

pane_id=$(tmux list-panes -t :$window_id -F '#{pane_active}#D' | grep '^1' | cut -c 2-)

fg_pid=$(tmux display-message -t :$window_id.$pane_id -p '#{pane_pid}' | xargs pgrep -P | xargs ps -o stat,pid= -p | grep '+' | awk '{print $2}')

if [ -z "$fg_pid" ]; then
    echo "No foreground process found in window $window_id"
    exit 1
fi

get_child_pids() {
    local parent_pid="$1"
    local child_pids=$(pgrep -P "$parent_pid")
    for pid in $child_pids; do
        echo "$pid"
        get_child_pids "$pid"
    done
}

pids_to_kill=$(echo "$fg_pid"; get_child_pids "$fg_pid")

processes_info=$(ps -o pid=,ppid=,comm= -p $pids_to_kill)

for pid in $pids_to_kill; do
    kill -9 "$pid" 2>/dev/null
done

~/.bybou/keybindings.tmux:
unbind-key k
bind-key k run '~/bin/_byobu_kill_process.sh'


We're gonna utilize bindkey to create a shortcut and built-in commands pgrep and pkill. As an additional information/demonstration I'll use ps with some of its options.
Let's go:
1. ps has some interesting parameters, the ones we're gonna focus on are T, -C <command name> and -o pid= (yes, nothing after =!).
NOTE: this entire paragraph is meant to be a showcase, a way to easily check the correctness of the real solution in the next one.

ps T prints processes running in the current terminal. As an example I created temporary symlink /bin/phps to my PhpStorm, so running phps & opens an instance of mentioned IDE in the background. After running it in one terminal (>/dev/null 2>&1 added so it won't print anything, & means "run in background"):

(you may also note that the number of background jobs running in the current terminal changed from green 0 to the red !1!)
Now here's how it looks in the second terminal:


Now we're gonna try ps -C <command name> - putting my phps as a searched command:

and in the other terminal we have:

Note, that the second terminal is pts/0 (check previous image), but on both we receive pts/1 as a result (correctly!) - since that's the terminal we're running our command.
Because of this behavior I began from ps T - so we can catch the PID of the process running in the current terminal.

Last parameter I'd like to elaborate on is -o pid=. It's an output modifier that simply makes the ps print only PID's, without the header (first line). The easiest way of explaining is always the visual way:


So - the last thing to do here is to combine all of the above. We're gonna simply use ps -C phps -o pid= on a result of ps T:

and in the other terminal:

As we can see we achieved the expected result - we can catch the PID of a chosen process, but only if it's running in the current terminal.


2. My real solution is based on 'pgrep and 'pkill' commands, since they fit better, but note that using above-mentioned ps would also work.
The main reason for using pgrep is its built-in parameter -s 0, documented as "Only match processes whose process session ID is listed. Session ID 0 is translated into pgrep's or pkill's own session ID.".

Then - let's see it in action:

and in the second terminal:

As shown - we can achieve what we did earlier wit ps, but with a single command. pkill is sister-like to pgrep, so it takes the same parameters. Let's see how it works - in the second terminal:

As expected - it didn't kill the process, because it doesn't belong to the current terminal. Now for the main console:

So - we finally achieved the result we wanted. The last step is to bind our command to a shortcut.
To create it for zsh we'll use the following command:
bindkey -s '^k' 'pkill <YOUR ACTUAL BINARY> -s 0\n'

(this particular example binds the command to CTRL+k combination)
Then just add it to your ~/.zshrc or /etc/zsh/zshrc (for global sourcing) - and you're done.



Bonus: Note, that pkill (and also kill for the matter of fact) sends SIGTERM signal by default (if none is specified), and if your process accepts other signals you can easily utilize it by using --signal <NAME> as an additional parameter to pkill. The purpose of that is i.e. to close the process gracefully. Normally the list of the signals that the particular daemon accepts is listed in man <NAME>, in the SIGNALS section. Example from man stunnel:
SIGNALS
       The following signals can be used to control stunnel in Unix environment:
       SIGHUP
           Force a reload of the configuration file.
           Some global options will not be reloaded:
           ·   chroot
           ·   foreground
           ·   pid
           ·   setgid
           ·   setuid
           The use of the 'setuid' option will also prevent stunnel from binding to privileged (<1024) ports during configuration reloading.
           When the 'chroot' option is used, stunnel will look for all its files (including the configuration file, certificates, the log file and the pid file) within the chroot
           jail.
       SIGUSR1
           Close and reopen the stunnel log file.  This function can be used for log rotation.
       SIGUSR2
           Log the list of active connections.
       SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGINT
           Shut stunnel down.

The list of available signals is easily available by using kill -l command.
So if you'd like to use i.e. equivalent of kill -9 <PROCESS> (which equals kill -SIGKILL <PROCESS>) - just add --signal SIGKILL (or simply: -9) to your pkill command.

Images of text are usually a bad idea.

@KamilMaciorowski in this particular case I must disagree. Images are added ONLY as an example of the output, and using real output makes my answer more reliable, images are kinda proof of work. Note, that all the actual commands are posted as a proper text

Real output may as well be posted as text, this will not make it unreal. In general users will assume your good intentions, there is no need to make the answer look "more reliable". What ultimately counts is if the solution works. I'm not going to do anything "hostile" to your answer or the images. Still, for me these colors and the prompt I'm not used to obfuscate the answer and make it worse; e.g. the clock is totally irrelevant, it only obfuscates. Posting text, preceding input with #  (root's prompt) or with $  (regular user's) and output with nothing would be much more readable.

@KamilMaciorowski since I already did all those - can we agree the images will stay, and I'll avoid inserting them in my next answer? Re-doing all the commands just to catch the output (to replace images) seems like a tedious job, especially at this stage of creating an answer.

Very well. This is a reasonable plan.

@KamilMaciorowski BTW - I have to agree with your statement about the clock in my prompt :) Any ideas for a replacement? Or should I just get rid of it?

That was a long answer with lots of explanations, but the actual answer is still unclear. If I understand correctly, the command you suggest is bindkey -s '^k' 'pkill <YOUR ACTUAL BINARY> -s 0\n'. Your solution assumes I know the binary name in advance, which I dont.

Yes, you can create a custom Byobu hotkey to kill the foreground process in the currently active Byobu window. Here’s how you can set it up:

Create a Script to Kill the Foreground Process
You’ll need to write a small script that identifies the foreground process in the active Byobu window and sends it a kill -9 signal.

Create a file called kill_foreground_process.sh in your home directory (or wherever you prefer):
#!/bin/bash

# Get the Byobu window number of the currently active window
window=$(tmux display-message -p '#I')

# Get the process ID (PID) of the foreground process running in the current window
pid=$(tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_active} #{pane_pid}' | grep '^1 ' | awk '{print $2}')

# If a PID was found, kill the process
if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
    kill -9 "$pid"
    echo "Killed process with PID $pid"
else
    echo "No active foreground process found."
fi



